# What does it mean when a block with the word "stub" is passed to let in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am trying to read a spec written by another developer quite a while ago, in order to update some tests and address all of the deprecation and other warnings. I am baffled as to the **intention/functionality of this particular line**, which is causing a warning:

```
let(:ftp) { stub }
```

It appears just inside a describe block in a spec for a rails model which does not appear to have a method by that name defined. In fact, the following test returns false:

```
MyModelName.respond_to?(:ftp) || MyModelName.new.respond_to?(:ftp)
```

Is this a common usage for stub in rspec? I have only ever seen it used in the documentation and elsewhere like:

```
MyModelName.stub(:method_name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stub` is a deprecated alias of `double`. In other words `let(:ftp) { stub }` returns you double object: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs

Calling `stub` on objects differs. It mocks given method name with fake implementation.

Also, `let` defines an object with given name within examples context. So `let(:foo) { ... }` has nothing to do with `MyModelName.respond_to?(:foo)`. Last one - just checks if `MyModelName` responds to method named `:foo`.